# How to flip the dropdown (Popover) uisng popper js

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, popper.js

In my application am showing dropdown(Popover) from button left side. If button is in browser right edge. I want to show button right edge to left edge .can anybody tell how to flip in popper js

Thanks

Comment: have you read https://popper.js.org/#example3?

Comment: where is your code? jfiddle can be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
var popper = new Popper(referenceElement, onLeftPopper, {
    placement: 'right',
    modifiers: {
        flip: {
            behavior: ['right', 'left']
        },
        preventOverflow: {
            boundariesElement: container,
        },
    },
});
```

Comment: @madalinivascu.I want to show in bottom only but button right edge need to start

Comment: you want to move it to the bottom if the popover is close to right?

Comment: yes it need to show in bottom but rith edge of button